# Error when building C++ application using KXmlGuiWindow

Tags: c++, kxml

I was following an [introductory tutorial for using the KDE Framework](https://develop.kde.org/docs/getting-started/main_window/) and ran into problems when compiling. The code is the same as in the tutorial.
The compiler outputs:

`fatal error: KXmlGuiWindow: No such file or directory`

My first thought was that I am simply missing a package so I used apt-cache search to search for kxml and installed libkf5xmlgui-dev. Despite that the error persists. I could not references to this error anywhere online. Has the import path been changed? Is another package required?

I am running Kubuntu 20.04.

I previously had to install other packages for compiling the "Hello World" program that did not yet include KXmlGuiWindow, but when I had installed them everything worked fine.

Edit:
`find /usr -name KXmlGuiWindow` gave me the output `/usr/include/KF5/KXmlGui/KXmlGuiWindow`. I use Atom for my code editor so I compile the program from a terminal by running the commands given in the tutorial which is `cmake .. && make` (from a build directory in the project's root directory).

The full output pf that command is

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Installing in the same prefix as Qt, adopting their path scheme.
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME - Success
-- Found KF5CoreAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5CoreAddons/KF5CoreAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.68.0") 
-- Found Gettext: /usr/bin/msgmerge (found version "0.19.8.1") 
-- Found KF5I18n: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5I18n/KF5I18nConfig.cmake (found version "5.68.0") 
-- Found KF5WidgetsAddons: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/KF5WidgetsAddons/KF5WidgetsAddonsConfig.cmake (found version "5.68.0") 
-- Found KF5: success (found suitable version "5.68.0", minimum required is "5.2.0") found components: CoreAddons I18n WidgetsAddons 
-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * ECM (required version >= 1.0.0)
 * Qt5Gui (required version >= 5.12.8)
 * Qt5 (required version >= 5.3.0)
 * Qt5Core (required version >= 5.12.0)
 * KF5CoreAddons (required version >= 5.2.0)
 * Gettext
 * KF5I18n (required version >= 5.2.0)
 * Qt5Widgets (required version >= 5.12.0)
 * KF5WidgetsAddons (required version >= 5.2.0)
 * KF5 (required version >= 5.2.0)

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/simon/Documents/Code/helloWorld/build
Scanning dependencies of target helloworld_autogen
[ 25%] Automatic MOC for target helloworld
[ 25%] Built target helloworld_autogen
Scanning dependencies of target helloworld
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/helloworld_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/helloWorld.cpp.o
In file included from /home/simon/Documents/Code/helloWorld/helloWorld.cpp:6:
/home/simon/Documents/Code/helloWorld/mainwindow.h:4:10: fatal error: KXmlGuiWindow: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <KXmlGuiWindow>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/helloWorld.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/helloworld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Adding the flag solved one of the errors, the one mentioned in the original post. I still get other errors, but I will look for existing solutions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to answer a question with rather a small amount of important data, but I'll try to give you some hints how to fix the problem

1. First,  what is the complete error message? Does it come from the compiler or linker? I guess it's the compiler. So most likely the line that makes the compiler unhappy is this:

```
#include <KXmlGuiWindow>
```

If so, you should see (and include here) the compiler message with the line number where it "saw" the problem, say "line 4".

2. Check if you have this file installed *somewhere*

```
find /usr -name KXmlGuiWindow
```

In my case the response is:

> /usr/include/KF5/KXmlGui/KXmlGuiWindow

If you can find it, add the usual `-IPATH_TO_THE_FILE` flag to the compilation flags.

If not, you don't have the required library. However, the list of the files included in your Kubuntu package can be found in the Internet, e.g here: (plus minus the Kubuntu version): https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libkf5xmlgui-dev/filelist
The file that the compiler can't find is on the list, in the `/usr/include/KF5/KXmlGui/` directory.

So, most likely adding

```
-I/usr/include/KF5/KXmlGui/
```

to the compiler flags should solve your problem.